# Pigeonhole Principle by using induction

Tags: combinatorics

Prove the generalized Pigeonhole Principle: Let $n$ and $m$ be natural numbers,
$X$ and $Y$ sets with $|X| = mn + 1,\; |Y | = n$, and $f : X\to Y$ a function.
Then there exists $y \in Y$ such that $|f^{-1}(y)|≥ m + 1$. (Hint: Do an induction on $m$).

I am sick of trying this problem. I don't know what else to do. My approach was to analyze the cardinality of $x$ when $m$ is increased by $1$. so $|x|=(m+1)n+1=m+n+1$. As we note the cardinality of $x$ goes up by $n$ and $n=|y|$. If one of the new elements goes to the element whose cardinality was $≥m+1$ then yes it increases by $1$ and therefore the inequality holds, but the problem is two show that the inequality holds when none of the new n elements added go the element used in the inductive hypothesis. Please help. I need to turn in this exercise today and I have been trying it like for $5$ hours with no result.

Comment: Here's a hint: you don't need to use the hint. You could always try proving it a different way. For instance, try to prove the contrapositive. edit: oops, looks like Stefan4024 beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $| f^{-1}(y) | \le m$ Then $y_1 \not= y_2 \implies f^{-1}(y_1) \cap f^{-1}(y_2) = \emptyset$, which come from the fact that $f$ is a well-defined function. Obviously now: $\bigcup_{y \in Y} f^{-1}(y) = X$, so therefore:

$$| Y | \cdot m \ge \left| \bigcup_{y \in Y} f^{-1}(y) \right|= | X | = mn + 1 \implies mn \ge mn+1.$$

So by the contradiction we get that there exists at least one $y \in Y$, s.t. $| f^{-1}(y) | \ge m+1$.